# 3D web map to QGIS

Tags: qgis, elevation, 3d, server

There is this 3D scan of Curitiba and I would like to know if there is a way to import the elevation data to QGIS. I’m looking to extract some elevation data of a specific area to make a physical model

https://geocuritiba.ippuc.org.br/portal/home/item.html?id=60189e0814544a029915280f776da5ab

[image]

Comment: you can use WMTS in QGIS https://geocuritiba.ippuc.org.br/server/rest/services/Hosted/ElevationLayer2019/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: It’s halfway there, I think. It seems to recognize the extent of the layer, but it’s blank. How did you find this link? @Mapperz